# Using Google Apps script, how to check if an email has a pdf attached to it, then forward it to another email address?

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, email-attachments

I managed to create a function that converts an email to a pdf and then it forwards it to another email address ( I used this great library made by Mike Greiling  :https://github.com/pixelcog/gmail-to-pdf).

but now I want to create another function that checks if the email already has an attachment, and then forward it right away.

here's my working function:

```
function saveExpenses() {

    GmailUtils.processStarred( 'label: test', 5, function(message) {

    // create a pdf of the message
    var pdf = GmailUtils.messageToPdf(message);

    // prefix the pdf filename with a date string
    pdf.setName(GmailUtils.formatDate(message, 'yyyy/MM/dd - ') + pdf.getName());   

     // send confirmation email to the original sender 
     var confirmationEmail = message.getFrom();

     // Get the name of the document to use as an email subject line.
     var subject =  pdf.getName();

     var body = "This is a confirmation that this receipt has been sent";

     // Send a confirmation email to the sender
     GmailApp.sendEmail(confirmationEmail, subject, body,  {attachments: [pdf]});

    return true;

  });
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution, actually it was pretty easy.
I guess I didn't think enough, so basically I just get all the attachments from the message with the function `getAttachments`which returns an array of `attachments`, I then just check if the length of the array is greater than 0 ( which means there are attachments in the email )
and if the result is 0, it means there are no attachments.

Here is what I did :

```
var attachment = message.getAttachments();

    if (attachment.length > 0 ) {
          // I add the code to deal with the attachment

    } else if  (attachment.length == 0 ) {
          // I add the code that I posted in the question above
    }
```